# F-bounded types and methods with type parameters at argument and return sites

Tags: scala, path-dependent-type, f-bounded-polymorphism

I have an F-bounded type, and my objective is to create a type-parametrized method in order to be able to reuse it. Here is the example code:

```
trait FType {
  type ThisType <: FType

  def deepCopy(): ThisType

}

class ConcreteType extends FType {

  override type ThisType = ConcreteType

  override def deepCopy(): ConcreteType = this

}

class ConcreteType2 extends FType {

  override type ThisType = ConcreteType2

  override def deepCopy(): ConcreteType2 = this

}

object FType {

  def deepCopy[T <: FType](_type: T): T = {
    _type.deepCopy()
  }

/*  def deepCopy2(c: ConcreteType2): ConcreteType2 = {
    c.deepCopy()
  }*/

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    //deepCopy2(new ConcreteType2)
  }

}
```

However, the code does not compile. The compiler throws this error:

```
Error:(29, 19) type mismatch;
 found   : _type.ThisType
 required: T
    _type.deepCopy()
```

I understand that it has something to to with path-dependent types since `_type.ThisType` is not the same type as `T`.

But how, then, can I take advantage of F-bounded types if the F-bounded type is not exactly the same as the type using the F-bounded type? If the types are not exactly the same, how is that `deepCopy2` compiles?

**Note**: I know I can avoid using type parameters in `deepCopy` by using method overloading for each of the concrete types.

Answer (score 5):

> If the types are not exactly the same, how is that deepCopy2 compiles?

That is quite simple. It works because there is no polymorphism involved. It's statically known that `ConcreteType2` has `deepCopy()` method that returns `ConcreteType2`. You could even remove `type ThisType` from whole hierarchy and it would still work the same way.

---

> But how, then, can I take advantage of F-bounded types if the F-bounded type is not exactly the same as the type using the F-bounded type?

You need to tell the compiler that it's the same, as you haven't specified enough. Let's take a look at an example that works and is polymorphic:

```
def deepCopy[A <: FType { type ThisType = A }](_type: A): A = _type.deepCopy()
//                      ^ --important bit-- ^
```

This defines a method that works for any `A` that is `FType` and also it's type member `ThisType` is set to `A`, tying them together. That means it would work for your definitions of `ConcreteType` and `ConcreteType2`. It would NOT compile, however, for classes that aren't defined properly, such as this one:

```
class Bogus extends FType {
  override type ThisType = ConcreteType2
  override def deepCopy(): ConcreteType2 = new ConcreteType2
}

deepCopy(new Bogus)
```

---

Alternatively, let's start with a slightly modified version of your method:

```
def deepCopyPD[A <: FType](_type: A): _type.ThisType = _type.deepCopy()
                                   ^path-dependent^
```

It puts no constraints on `ThisType`, but in fact compiler would be able to infer proper versions of it for all cases:

```
val x: ConcreteType2 = deepCopyPD(new ConcreteType2)
val y: ConcreteType2 = deepCopyPD(new Bogus) // yep, this invocation is possible with such signature
```

However, it is also possible to further add constraints using type equality evidence as implicit parameter:

```
def deepCopyPD2[A <: FType](_type: A)(implicit ev: _type.ThisType =:= A): A = _type.deepCopy()
```

This, once more, forbids the invocation with `Bogus`

Answer (score 2):

In F-bounded types, you'd normally have `ThisType` as a type parameter instead of a type member:

```
trait FType[ThisType <: FType] {
  def deepCopy(): ThisType    
}

class ConcreteType extends FType[ConcreteType] {
  override def deepCopy(): ConcreteType = this
}

// in object FType
def deepCopy[T <: FType[T]](_type: T): T = {
  _type.deepCopy()
}
```

Note the difference: in `FType.deepCopy` the compiler knows that the return type of `_type.deepCopy()` is `T`.

You *can* do the same with type members:

```
def deepCopy[T <: FType { type ThisType <: T }](_type: T): T = 
  _type.deepCopy()
```